# Google Maps API v3 Custom Button

Tags: button, google-maps-api-3

After having looked at the following question and answer ([Initiate polygon drawing from custom button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187758/initiate-polygon-drawing-from-custom-button?rq=1)) ,  trying the code and getting no results I am not sure what I am doing wrong. My code is as follows:

```
//button function
$(".btn > .icon-circle-blank").click(function(event){
    //stub for gmap radius drawing
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE);
})
```

I am able to initialize the drawing tools with

```
      var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        drawingModes: [
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
        ]
      }
    });
```

Usually I have drawingControl set to false and my custom button is not on the map.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your click function getting called at all? It looks like it's set to fire when the icon is clicked, rather than the button.

**Update**: `drawingManager` is outside the scope of your `click` functions. Since those event handlers are part of the page initialization, I recommend moving them inside the `initialize` function.

Comment: Thought that might be the case and so I changed the .btn > .icon-circle-blank to #circle and applied the id in my html. Still google maps give me nothing

Comment: @LucasS can you post your html snippet?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EHLXH/ and everything works save for font awesome (but its not essential to the code)

Comment: @LucasS See my updated answer. That should take care of the problem. Also, check out the dev tools of your browser for easy debugging.